# Expand first group and collapse remaining group by default using zk

Tags: java, zk

I have created a MyGroupModelList class by extending the AbstractGroupsModel class. I want first group present in MyGroupModelList should be expanded and remaining all other groups should be collapsed.

On the viewModel I have written Below.

```
private MyGroupModelList <TabData> summaryGroupModel;

@AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view){    
summaryGroupModel = getSummaryTabData(folderRSN);

if (summaryGroupModel != null && summaryGroupModel.getGroupCount() > 0) {
summaryGroupModel.addOpenGroup(0);
}
```

On the ZUL have written Below.

```
<zk>

 <window width="100%" height="100%"
    apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.test.MyGroupModelList ')">


    <listbox model="@bind(vm.summaryGroupModel.groupModel)">

        <listhead>
            <listheader label="Bill Number"></listheader>
            <listheader label="Bill Amount"></listheader>

        </listhead>

        <template name="model" var="Data">
            <listitem>
                <listcell>
                    <label value="@load(Data.billNumber)" />
                </listcell>
                <listcell>
                    <label value="@load(Data.billAmount)" />
                </listcell>

            </listitem>
        </template>
    </listbox>
</window>
</zk>
```

Above code is not expanding first group present in MyGroupModelList.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a sample demo example for this [expand-first-groupbox-and-collapse](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/06/expand-first-groupbox-and-collapse.html)

Or you can check this live demo code in [Zk fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1b73e2v/4-Simple-ListGroup-first-group-open)